# Nuxt await async + vuex

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Im using nuxt and vuex. In vuex im getting data:

```js
actions: {
    get_posts(ctx) {
      axios.get("http://vengdef.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts").then(post => {
        let posts = post.data;


        if (!posts.length) return;

        let medias_list = "";
        posts.forEach(md => {
          medias_list += md.featured_media + ","
        });
        medias_list = medias_list.slice(0, -1);


        let author_list = "";
        posts.forEach(md => {
          author_list += md.author + ","
        });
        author_list = author_list.slice(0, -1);


        axios.all([
          axios.get("http://vengdef.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?include=" + medias_list),
          axios.get("http://vengdef.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users?include=" + author_list),
          axios.get("http://vengdef.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories"),
        ]).then(axios.spread((medias, authors, categories) => {

          ctx.commit("set_postlist", {medias, authors, categories} );

        })).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        });


      })
    }
  },
```

In vuex state i have dynamic postlist from exaple below.
How i can use it in Nuxt?

In nuxt i know async fetch and asyncData.

```js
async fetch () {
    this.$store.dispatch("posts/get_posts");
}
```

Thats not working.

How i can say to nuxt, wait loading page, before vuex actions loading all data?

Comment: await this.$store.dispatch("posts/get_posts"); Maybe will be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mentioned there are:

- fetch hook
- asyncData

And differences are well described [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching)

The reason why your code is not working might be in your store action.
It should return a promise, try to add `return` before axios get method ->

```
get_posts(ctx) {
      return axios.get(...
    // ...
```

And then, on your page:

```
async fetch () {
    await this.$store.dispatch("posts/get_posts");
}
```

Also, in comment above you're saying that you dont want to commit data in store:

> ...load page only after vuex, i dont need to pass data in vuex

But you do it with this line:

```
ctx.commit("set_postlist", {medias, authors, categories} );
```

if you dont want to keep data in store, just replace line above with:

```
return Promise.resolve({ medias, authors, categories })
```

and get it on your page:

```
async fetch () {
    this.posts = await this.$store.dispatch("posts/get_posts");
    // now you can use posts in template 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Misread the actual question, hence the update

With Nuxt, you can either use `asyncData()`, the syntax will change a bit tho and the render will be totally blocked until all the calls are done.

Or use a combo of `fetch()` and some [skeletons](https://buefy.org/documentation/skeleton) to make a smooth transition (aka not blocking the render), or a loader with the `$fetchState.pending` helper.

More info can be found here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#the-fetch-hook

---

##### Older (irrelevant) answer

If you want to pass a param to your Vuex action, you can call it like this

```js
async fetch () {
  await this.$store.dispatch('posts/get_posts', variableHere)
}
```

In Vuex, access it like

```js
get_posts(ctx, variableHere) {
```

That you can then use down below.

---

PS: try to use `async/await` everywhere.

PS2: also, you can [destructure](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring) the context directly with something like this

```js
get_posts({ commit }, variableHere) {
  ...
  commit('set_postlist', {medias, authors, categories})
}
```

Comment: Thats not why i need, read post. I need to say nuxt wait, before vuex fetching data. And load page only after vuex, i dont need to pass data in vuex

Comment: @ЕвгенийВенеград if you want to have `fetch()` and something blocking, you need to export your fetching logic to a `middleware`. This should work fine.